# href link working for one item but not for another

Tags: html, css

I have an index.html that includes:

```
<li>
   <a href="imprint.html#imprint-link">
   <div class="main-menu-title">IMPRINT</div>
   </a>
</li>
```

When I click on this item another html file (imprint.html) is loaded, but when I click on Home, which includes the following code to go back to index.html, it doesn't work!

```
<a href="#index-link">
   <div class="main-menu-title">HOME</div>
</a>
```

What is wrong here?

Update 1: When hovering the mouse over the link I get:

[image]

Comment: In what way does it not work? What does it do, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: When I click on Home button not works to  send back to previous page (from imprint.html to index.html) @DavidThomas

Comment: here you should mention home page name : <a href="index.html#index-link">

Comment: Well, yes: you've used a fragment-identifier in the `href` which, by design, links to an element with an `id` equal to the `href` (your link will scroll to the element with `id="index-link`. If you want to navigate to another page you have to use a URL; for example: `<a href="index.html#index-link">`.

Comment: @EshgheCode please see updates.

Comment: @DavidThomas not works see updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this code :

```
     <a href="index.html">
           <div class="main-menu-title">HOME</div>
     </a>
```

inplace of :

```
     <a href="#index-link">
        <div class="main-menu-title">HOME</div>

     </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question.

> What's wrong here?

As a couple kind folks already *commented* and one person already provided a nice *solution*, clicking on your original link

```
href="#index-link"
```

while you are on the **imprint.html** page will **not** take you to your **index.html** page. Why? Because

```
<a href="#index-link">
  <div class="main-menu-title">HOME</div>
</a>
```

is saying, "Take me to an element on the current page (imprint.html) that has an ID of 'index-link'. If there is no element with and ID set to **index-link**, on the imprint.html page, nothing will happen. And, you will stay on the current page because you didn't specify an URL outside of the current page, which is still **imprint.html**.

So, with that current setup, you will not get to see **index.html**.